# DiG returns wrong DNS but apparently only on my network

Tags: domain-name-system

i'm asking this question cause something a bit odd is going on, i changed the DNS on my domain to point to digitalocean's nameservers, i created a domain on DigitalOcean as well with the same name and set it to point to my Droplet, and after giving it about 30 minutes to propagate i checked with DiG to see if the domain was pointing to my server as expected.

Somehow it still points to the wrong IP, so i checked using `dig @8.8.8.8` instead of just `dig` and it shows me the correct IP i was expecting, any whois tool online returns the correct droplet IP address for my domain, but for some reason it seems that in my network it's returning the wrong one.

`dig +trace +additional salesonline.pt`

trying to show a full trace returns only the following information

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> +trace +additional salesonline.pt
;; global options: +cmd
;; Received 12 bytes from 192.168.1.254#53(192.168.1.254) in 22 ms
```

Comment: What was the TTL of the old records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change things at the registry?

Are you sure 30 mins is long enough for the changes to propagate?  It looks like the expiry is set to 3600 seconds.

Comment: What do you mean by registry? I changed the nameservers on my Domain which should point the domain to the digitalocean nameservers.
If i run a proxy for instance i can see my site just fine though that domain, running on digitalocean's server, it's only on my local network that it fails and i can't really figure out why.

Comment: oh nevermind, it *JUST* updated now... it was just the propagation. never took me so long to propagate before, sorry for bothering you guys.
The TLL on the domains is set by the service itself not me, so i don't know what it is, i'm guessing it changes from country to country and in my country it just took longer.
Still somewhat surprised as it had never taken so long, it's been 4 hours since i changed the DNS.

Comment: When you do a dig, you'll see a number in the returned RR that is the number of seconds till it expires.

Comment: i see, they have it set to almost 24 hours, damn, thank you for the heads up!